# How to create a vertical line between icons (with example image)

Tags: html, css

After trying numerous things and searching the web I still can't find out how to create a similar vertical line between the icons as shown in the left ofthe image. Someone an idea on how to achieve this? Any help will be much appreciated!!

[image]

Comment: Would be nice if there was an image..

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] and take the [tour] to see how and what to ask. HINT: Post code and effort

Comment: Please explaining better the problem, maybe adding some images and what you have tried so far. The more specific you are, the more is possible to get help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use before pseudo code as sanjeev said and Here's how it is done. View in full page when you run the snippet. not sure what's the error code is for.

```css
.timeline {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  counter-reset: section;
}
.timeline:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 3px;
  background: #fdb839;
  left: 32px;
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
.timeline > li {
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  padding-top: 18px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-left: 90px;
}
.timeline > li:before,
.timeline > li:after {
  display: block;
}

.timeline > li:before {
  counter-increment: section;
  content: counter(section);
  background: #fdb839;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  left: -1px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: #Fff;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 15px solid #fff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.timeline > li:after {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<ul class="timeline">
  <li>
    asdfasdf
  </li>
  <li>
    asdfsdf
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create it using CSS :before Selector