# Getting error while downloading input file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have written a html code upload any random file from the computer. I want to download the same file what user chooses using jQuery/javascript. I have written the following code to do the same.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('input[type="file"]').change(function(e){
                var fileName = e.target.files[0].name;
                $("#file").attr("href", fileName);
                });
        });
     </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="file1" type="file" id="photo" name="photo" value="No file chosen"><br><br>
    <a id="file" href="" download>download</a>
</body>
</html>
```

But I am not getting error while downloading the file.How will I do this?

Comment: It is just adding the filename to the href of the <a> element. This means it's trying to download from siteaddress.com/filename, not from your local machine. Have a look at [download.js](http://danml.com/download.html), you need to convert the file to a format you can save in JavaScript then create the file for the browser to download.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried following code, It works :

`HTML:`

```
<input id="file1" type="file" id="photo" name="photo" value="No file chosen"><br><br>
        <a id="file" href="" download>download</a>
```

`Script`:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('input[type="file"]').change(function(e){
            var tmppath = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]);
            //alert(tmppath);
            $("#file").attr("href", tmppath);
         });
    });
</script>
```

Please find fiddle here : [Click here](https://jsfiddle.net/adminsunil/6oL5c6x6/)

Hope it helps you..

Happy coding .. :)

Comment: Thanks Sunil . Now it is working fine.I also want to attach two links for the above code snippet which should display the date when the file is uploaded and another link will provide the details of the person by whom the file is uploaded.Can you please suggest how will I do this?

Comment: attach two links, do you mean you want render two `<a></a>` tags. One should display the `Date` and the other link is for `Details` of person who is uploading the file ?
M I Right ?

Comment: yes.But I want to know how will I retrieve the date and person's details using jQuery/Javascript?

Comment: Yes by jQuery you can get the `Date` but for person's Details, Where you are going to retrieve the person details ? 
do you mean login person details ?

Comment: Please refer the link "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37940355/how-to-create-a-vertical-line-between-icons-with-example-image".As you can see in the snapshot particular file is uploaded and person's details is being displayed on the webpage.How will I implement the same?

Comment: Do one thing put your `Person Name` in some container or in any html attribute from there we can retrieve the name. Please let me know if not clear

Comment: I have gone through few materials and seen it needs .asp or any file which interact with server. I have no idea about backend coding. Is it possible to retrieve the date when the file is uploaded?

Comment: Check my fiddle again: https://jsfiddle.net/adminsunil/6oL5c6x6/2/

you will get the date also. 
Thanks :)